# Android-SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android.I want to save my name  in Sqlite database when i enter the text in TextEdit and clicking the save button .I have created a database as name.db.I do know how to link the text in TextEdit and button  to the database. Please Help me out .Sample codes Will be were useful.Thanks in advance...

Comment: facing same problem any use full answer please....

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite database is an open source database which provide relation data.It don't need any server or hosting it localy placed in android devices. To create and upgrade the android sqlite database you will need to extends SqliteOpenHelper class from child class. In this way you can create and upgrade your database.
Blog: https://itmulc.blogspot.com/2016/08/android-sqlite-database-with-complete.html
Here you can get more help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8-Z85oPNmQ